# isolated scope inside angular material dialog template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

According to [angular material dialog demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog), a custom dialog window can have a html template and a controller with `$scope` injected.

What's the relationship of this controller's `$scope` and the containing controller?

In other words, how can I pass data from top level for example `$scope.status` into "dialog.tmpl.html"

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dialog1.tmpl.html">
   <p>
     {{status}}
   </p>
</script>
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How are you opening the dialog? Are you passing a `scope` property? See https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#show

Comment: got it. I should call `$mdDialog.show` with `scope:$scope`. thanks